# How can I set the output of now() in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, testing, stored-procedures, pure-function

We want to run automated tests on MySQL stored procedures and functions wher the tests compare actual and expected values.

The trouble is, even if we run a fixture script before each test, most of our routines can return different results given the same inputs- we do a lot of datetime stuff that relies on `now`. (`now` is the built-in function for returning the current datetime.)

How can we "freeze" what `now` returns in our test database?

The best solution I can think of is to replace all calls to `now` to calls to a custom function. In our prod database, this custom function will just call the built-in `now`, and in our dev database it will return a static date.

Is there an easier way, such as something like `SET global.CURRENT_TIME = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';`?

Comment: How many places do you have it

Comment: All over the place. My solution would work if we were to do a database dump, find-and-replace, then re-load. It's just ugly and requires discipline to never use the real `now` function directly.

Comment: I will type up an answer. Perhaps it is thumbs up.